# battleships game - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a Haskell beginner, and I have problem with my homework.
Assignment of this homework is down below. I really need help.

I must implement the function ships which has 2 arguments. First argument is a list of strings representing play field of one player row by row from top to bottom ('o' - square containing a ship, ' ' - empty square). Second list contains coordinates of squares attacked by second player. Print actual state of a play in the way where every row and column will be labelled by its number or letter, 'o' will be square with ship not attacked yet, 'x' square with ship already attacked, '.' already attacked empty square, ' ' empty square not attacked yet. You can consider that the size of play-field is 10x10.

```
type Result = [String]
ships :: Result -> [(Char, Int)] -> Result
sampleInput = ["  o    o  ",
           "      ooo ",
           "   oo     ",
           "          ",
           "     o    ",
           "     o    ",
           "     o    ",
           "          ",
           "          ",
           "  oooo    "]
```

and this should be an input and output

```
Prelude>pp(ships sampleInput [('a',1),('d',1),('d',2),('c',1),('b',1),('e',1),('f',1),('g',1),('c',7),('c',10)])
             10  x    o
             9      ooo
             8   oo
             7  .
             6     o
             5     o
             4     o
             3
             2   .
             1..xxxx.
              abcdefghij
```

can someone help me, how the code should look like?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform the input grid into the output grid by mapping a function over each cell of the grid.  The mapping function is going to need the coordinates of the cell and the content of the cell.  The coordinates are needed to see if the other player fired at that location, and the contents are needed in order to know whether anything was hit.

Mapping can be done with `map`.  Since the grid is 2d, you will need to map over the rows, and for each row, map over the columns of that row.

The coordinates of the row or column can be attached prior to mapping by `zip`ping with an infinite `..` range so that you get a pair of a coordinate in that dimension and a value in that dimension.

I.e.

```
zip [0..] xs
```

Labels each element of `xs` with a zero-based index.

You can test if a coordinate is a member of the shot list with `elem`.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58954/getting-the-index-x-y-of-a-char-in-a-2d-list-in-haskell